# Xamarin & Android - crash on exiting from method

Tags: android, xamarin, crash, httpclient

I don't know what can I tell more.
I have this method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsyncRequest(string uri, string content, HttpMethod method, bool tryReauthorizeOn401 = true)
{
    HttpRequestMessage rm = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
        rm.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(rm);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && tryReauthorizeOn401)
    {
        var res = await AuthenticateUser();
        if(res.user == null)
            return response;
        return await SendAsyncRequest(uri, content, method, false);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Nothing special. 
client.SendAsync(rm) is executed, response.StatusCode is Ok.
Application just crashes when exiting from this method.

Output shows me just this assert:

```
12-16 20:09:22.025 F/        ( 1683): * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4957, condition `is_ok (error)' not met, function:set_set_notification_for_wait_completion_flag, Could not execute the method because the containing type is not fully instantiated. assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
12-16 20:09:22.025 F/libc    ( 1683): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1683 (omerang.Android)
```

And nothing more. 
client is HttpClient.
I have setting in my Android project: **HttpClient Implementation** set to Android.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

**edit**

SendAsyncRequest is used like that:

```
public async Task<(HttpResponseMessage response, IEnumerable<T> items)> GetListFromRequest<T>(string uri)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await SendAsyncRequest(uri, null, HttpMethod.Get);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return (response, null);

    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(content);
    return (response, new List<T>(items));
}
```

Comment: `...containing type is not fully instantiated...` How are you consuming the SendAsyncRequest method? i.e. Without the usage pattern, I would assume you are using Result or such, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Look at my edited question.

Comment: @AdamJachocki keep moving up the call stack to make sure you are not making any `.Result` blocking calls that may be causing a deadlock.

Comment: I don't. What's more, everything works on WinForms (this project is common project for Winforms and Xamarin). But here it just crashes without any exception. Debugger just ends it work and VS stops debugging.

Comment: @AdamJachocki Ok what calls `GetListFromRequest`, and then what calls that and so on? Show a [mcve] that can be used to help reproduce and diagnose the problem. Could also be a fire and forget problem but there are not enough details provided for a definite assessment.

Comment: Ok, I was able to do some minimal project. But in this example project crash happens earlier: https://github.com/AdamJachocki/XamarinTest

Comment: I'm not seeing a crash with your sample. Adding a couple of `Console.WriteLine` methods also seem to execute all the code fine and the application remains running.

Comment: Hmm, so what might be the cause? Different VS versions? Maybe some extension? But I have quite clean environment

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had to delay the project :/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the provided example project code you provided

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    Controller c = new Controller();
    TodoItem item = await c.GetTodoItem(1);
    TodoItem item2 = await c.GetTodoItem(2);
}
```

You are calling `async void` fire and forget on startup.

You wont be able to catch any thrown exceptions, which would explain why the App crashes with no warning.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

`async void` should only be used with event handlers, so I would suggest adding an event and handler.

based on the provided example, it could look like as follows

```
public partial class App : Application {
    public App() {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    private even EventHander starting = delegate { };
    private async void onStarting(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        starting -= onStarting;
        try {
            var controller = new Controller();
            TodoItem item = await controller.GetTodoItem(1);
            TodoItem item2 = await controller.GetTodoItem(2);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //...handler error here
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart() {
        starting += onStarting;
        starting(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

With that, you should now at least be able to catch the thrown exception to determine what is failing.

Comment: I thought that calling async void in OnStart event is ok. But I will catch exceptions as you said and then will see what will happen.

Comment: @AdamJachocki I've seen documentation examples showing that, but `OnStart` is **not** an event handler, which would make it ill advised to use `async void` on that method.

Comment: Nothing helped :( I did exactly what you have shown, but the result is the same. Of course no exception is thrown.

Comment: @AdamJachocki lets see if we can narrow down the exception. if you put a break point in the catch does it hit?

Comment: No. And it's all about that. Nothing is thrown. Breakpoint doesn't hit in catch scope. Debugging just ends and I can see a message on emulator saying that my app stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

try to update your compileSdkVersion to a higher version and check.
also try following

> ```
> >     Go to: File > Invalidate Caches/Restart and select Invalidate and Restart
> ```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Forgot to tell it.